# First element that is floated right

Tags: css, css-selectors

I set `margin` for some elements:

```
button {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
}

a {
  margin: 10px 20px 0 0;
}
```

Now, whenever I `float: right` any of these elements, I want to set `margin-right: 0` for the first right-floated element. Something like below:

```
.float-right {
  float: right;
  /* only for first instance */ margin-right: 0;
}
```

What are the options to do it?

A few constraints:

- I have different margins for different elements, and I want the `.float-right` class to be generic, so I cannot set `margin-right: 0` to the class, and then set a margin for other instances of the right-floated element (`.float-right ~ .float-right`).
- In my case it is not practical to wrap the elements into a container so I could simply use `:first-child` pseudo selector.

Below is a simple example where I have a logo `<a>` and a login `<a>` - the latter is floated right, it is not the first element of type `<a>`, and I need `margin-right` to be `0`.

```css
a {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

.float-right:first-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="">LOGO</a>
<a href="" class="float-right">Login | Register</a>
```

Comment: I have included a very simple fiddle to illustrate the situation. This is a simplification, however, the constraints I have indicated still apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are really asking for is `first-of-class` which, as yet, does not exist.

You can target, however, the first element with a class that immediately follows one that does NOT have that class with the `:not()` seelctor and the immediate sibling selector.

As follows:

```css
a {
  margin-right: 50px;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
*:not(.float-right) + .float-right {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="">LOGO</a>
<a href="" class="float-right">Login | Register</a>
```

This is not ideal as it's not really extendable to a large degree but it does offer a solution to your specific request.

Comment: Interesting approach. Even though it doesn't work in cases where the right-floated element is also the first element in a container, if I combine the declaration like so `.float-right:first-child, *:not(.float-right) + .float-right`, it works in all cases

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a jQuery solution, you can try using jQuery's .first() to get you the first .float-right element in the document:

```
$("body").find(".float-right").first().css("margin-right","0");
```

Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .first() method constructs a new jQuery object from the first element in that set. You can read more about it here: https://api.jquery.com/first/

I created a jsFiddle for you to illustrate - https://jsfiddle.net/0ccb36mz/

Answer (score -2):

Please try like this:

```
.float-right:first-child{
   margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi. I have included a link to a fiddle in my question to illustrate a situation where your suggestion would, unfortunately, not work...